# Which web3 decentralized wallet is suitable to store my crypto assets and lock some of the tokens for certain time?

Tags: blockchain, distributed, wallet

I have some tokens and coins of various blockchain networks but i do not want them to store in centralized exchanges. What decentralized wallet is better to use and multifunction? I also want to lock some tokens for a certain time period.

I tried metamask but i cannot lock tokens there.